# Why my code returns an http 0 response instead of expected 200?

Tags: php

I've a php function that checks if a list of URLs are still alive (checking HTTP status code) , and it works pretty well. When the URL can't be reached, the status code displayed is "0" (ex: http://81.200.15.122/mjpg/video.mjpg). But in some cases, even if the URL is alive, the response is "0".

For example, this URL is alive but my code returns a "0" HTTP status code: http://81.149.56.38:8083/mjpg/video.mjpg

If I use an online HTTP checker (https://www.portcheckers.com/http-header-check), it confirms that the status code should be 200.
I thought that the problem could be related with the fact that it's a mjpg video flow URL, but this other similar URL returns the expected 200 status code: http://204.195.155.5/mjpg/video.mjpg

Here's the code:

```
function get_response($url) {
    $handles = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_exec($handles);
    $httpresponse = curl_getinfo($handles, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo ("http status code: ". $httpresponse);
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Looks to me this could be a timeout issue. curl has two options: `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` - The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickSimard. I have tested your code and a command like `$ curl -Is http://81.149.56.38:8083/mjpg/video.mjpg | head -n 1` as well and both return 200 or 0 eventually. Depending on your needs, try to increase your timeout, ignore some 0 results or fix your timeout

Comment: Since increasing the timeout do not resolve my problem, I also tried to check if the URL returns some content using this: `<?php
        
         $section = file_get_contents('http://81.149.56.38:8083/mjpg/video.mjpg', FALSE, NULL, 20, 14);
         var_dump($section);
         ?>` but it also returns that there's no content…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem: my hosting server firewall has some ports closed, that do not allow a response for some URLs.

Comment: In which case, curl_getinfo() will return *false*, not 0

Answer (score 0):

cURL returns 0 on timeout. Some URL's can have a higher latancy then others. If cURL reaches the time out it will return 0 because the query is incomplet.

```
function get_response($url) {
    $handles = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($handles, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($handles);
    $httpresponse = curl_getinfo($handles, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo ("http status code: ". $httpresponse);
}
```

Change the values to optimize your code. You should run this in a cron and save results in your sql table to avoid slowing down the page. You can also add a "last scanned 1h ago" or something like that. Users will have the list served instantly and server side will have planty of time to query every urls.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. But even with very large timeout values, I still get a 0. I've looked at other `curl` options that could help, but didn't find anything.